# android trying to save data using prefrences, does not work

Tags: android, preferences

I'm trying to learn how to use SharedPrences to save data.

In the test code below, getString returns no value, instead of 'ted', but I cannot figure out why.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    SharedPreferences pre=getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    pre.edit().putString("label","ted");
    pre.edit().commit();

    String tr;
    tr=pre.getString("label","no value");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy, `edit()` *creates* an Editor. You're putting the value in one and committing in another one. Just save the `edit()` return value in an Editor variable and call `commit()` in that.

Answer (score 4):

of course both answers are right but dmon's solution is much more easer and short:)

its enough to rewrite your code like this :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

SharedPreferences pre=getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
pre.edit().putString("label","ted").commit();

String tr=pre.getString("label","no value");
```

Answer (score 2):

Could it be because you re-call the `edit()` function? try this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    SharedPreferences pre=getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor ed = pre.edit();

    ed.putString("label","ted");
    ed.commit();

    String tr;
    tr=pre.getString("label","no value");
}
```

Comment: Agh, missed it by -that- much.