# How to save the information in the textfield that the user has entered for the user to enter the program again?

Tags: android, flutter

Hello I have an app that the user enters his name in a textfield
How to save his name for next time that he opens the app ?

I want the text field to be filled automatically and the user does not need to enter his name.
please help me to solve that

Comment: Use `SharedPreferences` or `DataStore`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [android trying to save data using prefrences, does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5885081/android-trying-to-save-data-using-prefrences-does-not-work)

Comment: You can refer the [link](https://www.androidauthority.com/how-to-store-data-locally-in-android-app-717190/) for understanding different ways to store data in android

Comment: Hey dude post some code not your requirements so we can update it and look for possible solutions